# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/mnt/sample.txt' if empty?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pymysql

It's been 2 weeks that I am trying to load data from text file into the SQL table usin gpython connector. I am able to load data successfuly without any condition like:

```
loadData35= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '%s' "  %completePath35 + "INTO TABLE %s" %tblname35
```

But now I want to load data only if the table is empty.

I have tried to use if else statements but was not successful because of the limitations of SQL Queries. Following is my basic code and I want to apply if condition on the load statement that it get executed only if the table is empty (previously not loaded).

```
sql35= 'CREATE TABLE if not exists %s (Datum varchar(50), Uhrzeit varchar(13), UpsACT_V varchar(6), UpsPRE_V varchar(6), IpsACT_A varchar(6), IpsPRE_A varchar(6))' %(tblname35)

myCursor.execute(sql35)
myConnection.commit()

loadData35= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '%s' "  %completePath35 + "INTO TABLE %s" %tblname35
myCursor.execute(loadData35)
myConnection.commit()
```

I was wodering that are we able to do this conditional SQL loading using python connector?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL, MariaDB, and connectors don't presently work well for conditional operations like you mention.

Your best approach is this: query the table for contents in one query, then perform your load in the next query. The best query for finding if the table exists and is empty:

```
   SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table);
```

This looks for any row in the table. It returns zero if empty, one if not. Once you know whether the table is present and empty, you can load it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I tried to embed this in my code as
 
`select35='SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM %s)' %(tblname35) myCursor.execute(select35)`
 using python connector but I got the following error: 
 `Traceback (most recent call last): File "38select1.py", line 52, in <module> myCursor.execute(sql35) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 464, in execute raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found.") mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found. ` @O. Jones

Comment: Apart from the above error, I tried to save the result of `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table);` in a variable temp as `temp=SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table);` but that was also not successfully executed. I am wondering if this is also possible to do or not?